# How to get the sum of data from a table (of a specific range)?

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel sheet has a table that copies data from an SQL database. This table has data of the usage of dies by machines from day 1 till today. There are data of multiple machines in the table.

```
------------------------------------------
| Machine |   Date   |  Die ID   | Usage |
------------------------------------------
|   A1    | 20171215 |    AAA    |  100  |
|   A1    | 20171216 |    AAA    |  150  |
|   A1    | 20171217 |    AAA    |   80  |
    .
    .
    .
|   A1    | 20180105 |    AAA    |  200  |
|   B2    | 20171220 |    BBB    |  500  |
|   B2    | 20171221 |    BBB    |  230  |
    .
    .
    .
|   B2    | 20180105 |    BBB    |  410  |
------------------------------------------
```

Now I would like to add another table that gets the total usage of a die from a specific point of date (Last Service Date) until today.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Machine | Die ID |   Last Service Date  |   Today  | Accumulative Usage |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    A1   |   AAA  |       25/12/2017     | 5/1/2018 |                    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    B2   |   BBB  |        1/1/2018      | 5/1/2018 |                    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Machine is keyed in based on SQL table and Die ID is based on the SQL table.
This Last Service Date is obtained from another table & Today is using latest date formula.

All formulas are written in VBA and copied as values. Now I'm having issues in coming up with the formula for Accumulative Usage.

Starting small using the formula:

```
=SUM(Table10[Usage])
```

will only give me the total for the entire column (including data from machine A1 and B2) which is not what I want.

Is there anything I can add to this formula to not only have it calculate the sum based on name of Die ID, but also based on the range set by Last Service Date? Or do I need to use another formula entirely?

Comment: You can solve by  SQL  :  Select machine ,[die ID] , max (date),sum (usage) from table where date <= date Group by machine, [die ID]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SUMIF` function should do what you are looking for.  Consider your first request (sum based on Die ID), you can use:

```
=SUMIF(Table10[Die ID],"=AAA",Table10[Usage])
```

You can then elaborate that for date range as well.

Comment: Your ides was a great starting point since I had no idea that such a formula existed. Thanks to this I went a level deeper and used a SUMIFS formula. Now my formula is `=SUMIFS(Table10[Usage],Table10[Die ID],"=AAA",Table10[Date],">=25/12/2017"` However the main issue now is that when I place it in VBA the value just returns 0. For now I'll put it in the table itself on Excel first.

Comment: yes `SUMIFS` for multiple criteria is the cleanest.  Please accept this answer if you found it helpful.  thanks.